# How to align the header logo with the menu?

Tags: html, css

I'm having some problems with aligning the logo with the menu options on CSS/SCSS.

What it should look like:

[image: What it should look like]

How it is now:

[image: How it is now]

CSS and HTML code:

```css
nav {
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
}

.nav-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.logo-app {
  height: 60px;
  width: 15em;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  padding-top: 3px;
}

.buttons {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <img src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="brand-logo" class="logo-app">
  <div class="buttons">
    <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="aboveMenu">
      <span>Sass</span>
    </button>
    <mat-menu #aboveMenu="matMenu" yPosition="above">
      <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
    </mat-menu>

    <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="aboveMenu"><span>Components</span></button>
    <mat-menu #aboveMenu="matMenu" yPosition="above">
      <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
    </mat-menu>

    <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="aboveMenu"><span>JavaScript</span></button>
    <mat-menu #aboveMenu="matMenu" yPosition="above">
      <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
    </mat-menu>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Simplest to consider is just making that `.buttons` class be inline-block, `display: inline-block`. The reason the image is rendered above is because the buttons div is filling the entire width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the `nav` element a flexbox container.

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.logo-app {
  flex: none;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 1px;
}

.buttons {
  flex: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60" alt="brand-logo" class="logo-app">
  
  <div class="buttons">
    <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="aboveMenu">
      <span>Sass</span>
    </button>
    <mat-menu #aboveMenu="matMenu" yPosition="above">
      <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
    </mat-menu>

    <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="aboveMenu"><span>Components</span></button>
    <mat-menu #aboveMenu="matMenu" yPosition="above">
      <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
    </mat-menu>

    <!-- hiding some buttons for better small demo
    <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="aboveMenu"><span>JavaScript</span></button>
    <mat-menu #aboveMenu="matMenu" yPosition="above">
      <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
    </mat-menu> 
    -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Awesome. It helped me so much. But now I have an element on menu that I need to throw to the right. How can I do it? Float doesn't work now

Comment: That's a different question and shouldn't be posed in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go...

Just put `<img src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="brand-logo" class="logo-app">` inside `<div class="buttons">...</div>`.

```css
nav {
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
}

.nav-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.logo-app {
  height: 60px;
  width: 15em;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  padding-top: 3px;
}

.buttons {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>
  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet' integrity='sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl' crossorigin='anonymous'>
</head>

<body>

  <nav>
    <div class="buttons">
      <img src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="brand-logo" class="logo-app">
      <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="aboveMenu">
          <span>Sass</span>
        </button>
      <mat-menu #aboveMenu="matMenu" yPosition="above">
        <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
      </mat-menu>

      <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="aboveMenu"><span>Components</span></button>
      <mat-menu #aboveMenu="matMenu" yPosition="above">
        <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
      </mat-menu>

      <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="aboveMenu"><span>JavaScript</span></button>
      <mat-menu #aboveMenu="matMenu" yPosition="above">
        <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
      </mat-menu>
    </div>
  </nav>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That seems like an undesired (and unnecessary) change. That div was obviously intended as a wrapper for buttons, not a logo.